# Exporting Tensorflow Models for Eigen Only Environments

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Has anyone seen any work done on this? I'd think this would be a reasonably common use-case. Train model in python, export the graph and map to a sequence of eigen instructions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anything like this is available, but it is definitely something that would be useful. There are some obstacles to overcome though:

- Not all operations are implemented by Eigen.
- We'd need to know how to generate code for all operations we want to support.
- The glue code to allocate buffers and schedule work can get pretty gnarly.

It's still a good idea though, and it might get more attention posted as a feature request on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/